# Git how to merge conflict after mergetool

Tags: git

I use mergetool in git and it pops up opendiff, which I like. I review the changes and choose what should go where. I hit "save" then look back at terminal. it asks me `Was the merge successful? [y/n]` i answer yes, but i don't know how to say "use the new merge file i just saved! not theirs, not ours, but the one I JUST saved"

```
Normal merge conflict for 'www/httpdocs/manifest/subsectionmanager-storage':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
Hit return to start merge resolution tool (opendiff): 
www/httpdocs/manifest/subsectionmanager-storage seems unchanged.
Was the merge successful? [y/n] y

Normal merge conflict for 'www/httpdocs/workspace/themes/active/less/common.less':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
Hit return to start merge resolution tool (opendiff): 
www/httpdocs/workspace/themes/active/less/common.less seems unchanged.
Was the merge successful? [y/n] ^[[A
www/httpdocs/workspace/themes/active/less/common.less seems unchanged.
Was the merge successful? [y/n] y
kirkstrobeck:atheycreek kirkstrobeck$ git add .
kirkstrobeck:atheycreek kirkstrobeck$ git add -u
kirkstrobeck:atheycreek kirkstrobeck$ git commit -m 'merged'
[master f6fed72] merged
 12 files changed, 1330 insertions(+), 29 deletions(-)
 mode change 100644 => 100755 www/httpdocs/workspace/data-sources/data.status_all_entries.php
 mode change 100644 => 100755 www/httpdocs/workspace/data-sources/data.twitter.php
 mode change 100644 => 100755 www/httpdocs/workspace/data-sources/data.twitter_latest_entry.php
 create mode 100755 www/httpdocs/workspace/themes/active/less/common.less.orig
 mode change 100644 => 100755 www/httpdocs/workspace/uploads/members/photos/amy_mcreynolds-4fb2e70566fb9.jpg
 mode change 100644 => 100755 www/httpdocs/workspace/uploads/members/photos/rachel-4fb2e793b13bd.jpg
 mode change 100644 => 100755 www/httpdocs/workspace/uploads/members/photos/tim-4fb3da80b15e3.jpg
 mode change 100644 => 100755 www/httpdocs/workspace/xml-importers/xml-importer.twitter.php
 mode change 100644 => 100755 www/httpdocs/workspace/xml-importers/xml-importer.ustream.php
 mode change 100644 => 100755 www/httpdocs/workspace/xml-importers/xml-importer.vimeo.php
 mode change 100644 => 100755 www/mysql/atheycreek_2012-05-16.sql
kirkstrobeck:atheycreek kirkstrobeck$ git stash apply
Auto-merging www/httpdocs/workspace/themes/active/less/common.less
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in www/httpdocs/workspace/themes/active/less/common.less
Auto-merging www/httpdocs/manifest/subsectionmanager-storage
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in www/httpdocs/manifest/subsectionmanager-storage
kirkstrobeck:atheycreek kirkstrobeck$
```

---

```
kirkstrobeck:atheycreek kirkstrobeck$ git config --global --list
user.name=kirkstrobeck
user.email=kirk@strobeck.com
user.user=kirkstrobeck
user.token=fd0010cb7e13a3f9bafe9766cfa81e7c
core.editor=nano
core.excludesfile=/Users/kirkstrobeck/.gitignore_global
github.user=kirkstrobeck
github.token=fd0010cb7e13a3f9bafe9766cfa81e7c
difftool.sourcetree.cmd=/Applications/Kaleidoscope.app/Contents/MacOS/ksdiff -w "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
difftool.sourcetree.path=
mergetool.sourcetree.cmd=/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" -ancestor "$BASE" -merge "$MERGED"
mergetool.sourcetree.trustexitcode=true
difftool.Kaleidoscope.cmd=ksdiff-wrapper git "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
difftool.prompt=false
diff.tool=Kaleidoscope
mergetool.keepbackup=true
kirkstrobeck:atheycreek kirkstrobeck$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `opendiff` isn't configured correctly in git. You should have the following line in your

```
git config mergetool.<tool>.trustExitCode true
```

> If the custom merge tool correctly indicates the success of a merge
>   resolution with its exit code, then the configuration variable
>   mergetool..trustExitCode can be set to true. Otherwise,
>   git-mergetool will prompt the user to indicate the success of the
>   resolution after the custom tool has exited.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.3/git-mergetool.html

Comment: Could you update your question with your current git config `git config --global --list`?

Comment: I don't think there is anything broken.. I just don't know how to say "commit/use/add the merge I just saved"

Comment: The problem is that git can't figure out whether the merge was successful or not based on opendiff's exit code. Look like you're also using a script for launching opendiff, what's the content of opendiff-w.sh?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the following command in order to accept the result of your merge as the new code to use:

```
git config --global mergetool.[tool].trustExitCode true
```